# How to debug EEFileLoadException thrown inside WPF InitializeComponent()?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, exception

My C# application is seeing lots of `EEFileLoadException`s in the Visual Studio output window. I cannot figure out how to **get any specific details of this exception**. There are a lot of these and they appear to consume a lot of runtime when they occur.

**Specifically what I want to find out is what file is failing to be loaded.**

If I turn on the Visual Studio setting "C++ Exceptions, <All C++ Exceptions not in this list>" then the debugger will in fact break on the exception, but there is no useful detail. It shows this:

[image]

There is no other detail I can find... Neither this popup window nor anything else I am aware of in the IDE will show more detail (unlike if it were a .NET exception).

---

Attempts to get information on the exception:

- Using `$exception` in the immediate window does not work (its not recognized, even when the IDE has flagged the exception).
- I am not able to try / catch this exception in C# code. It just doesn't activate the catch block, being caught internally by the CLR I assume. I tried like this:

  ```
       try { InitializeComponent(); }
       catch { }
  ```
- I watched the process using Process Monitor. However I
  was surprised to see no sign of any failed file loads whatsoever. (?)
- I also ran [API Monitor](http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor) on the process; this showed that
  `"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.Desktop.dll"` was being
  loaded, though I couldn't easily tell if it was not found or loaded
  successfully. But since this file **is present** in the location that it was being
  loaded from, this probably is unrelated. I didn't see anything else useful.

---

My app is constructed like this:

- Native EXE (written in VB6) which calls C# code through COM.
- .NET code which includes some WPF screens

*When debugging* I have the Visual Studio IDE actually run the VB6 IDE instead of the compiled EXE. The VB6 code then calls back into the C# code at various points. When that happens is where these exceptions arise.

The exceptions occur during the various WPF `InitializeComponent()` calls. It does not occur in my own code directly.

---

The exceptions look like this in the output window:

```
Exception thrown at 0x74D42802 in VB6.EXE: Microsoft C++ exception: EEFileLoadException at memory location 0x0019663C.
Exception thrown at 0x74D42802 in VB6.EXE: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.
Exception thrown at 0x74D42802 in VB6.EXE: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.
Exception thrown at 0x74D42802 in VB6.EXE: Microsoft C++ exception: EEFileLoadException at memory location 0x00195E64.
Exception thrown at 0x74D42802 in VB6.EXE: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.
Exception thrown at 0x74D42802 in VB6.EXE: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.
Exception thrown at 0x74D42802 in VB6.EXE: Microsoft C++ exception: EEFileLoadException at memory location 0x0019699C.
Exception thrown at 0x74D42802 in VB6.EXE: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.
Exception thrown at 0x74D42802 in VB6.EXE: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.
...
```

(way more than that... it goes on and on). Note that VB6.EXE is the process name because of the way I run in the IDE, as noted above. Its not actually VB6 itself generating these exceptions. They occur only when `InitializeComponent()` is called.

---

The application actually functions perfectly OK if I ignore the exceptions. So this might just be an issue in the debugging environment. But I'd still like to get to the bottom of it.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer, but at least a workaround.

The reason these exceptions were being handled by the debugger at all was because I had been working on a C# project which referenced a C++/CLI project, and I needed to debug in to the C++ code called by the latter. So I had mixed-mode debugging enabled.

Turning this off eliminated the exceptions - at least in the sense that the debugger no longer cares about them. I assume (?) that they may still be occurring behind the scenes.

This feature of VS [is shown here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-debug-in-mixed-mode?view=vs-2019):
[image]

Of course, when I need mixed-mode again I'll have to turn it back on and live with the performance degradation of the exceptions. But at least that's an improvement for me most of the time.

Comment: Hi, @StayOnTarget. Does this solution solve your problem? If it is solved, you can click ‘✔’ to accept it as an answer. It is helpful for community members to solve the similar problems.

Comment: @HuiLiu-MFST not fully, as mentioned it was just a workaround, it didn't really get to the bottom of why the exception occurred nor why it was so difficult to debug.